# How to disable entering custom user text to Rails form.select f

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, select, client

I want to display form select element **without** the option of entering custom text.

The current behaviour is:

The user can type characters in the input field but the default option will be selected.

Expected behaviour:

To **not allowed entering text** at all.

*Rails* code

```
     %dd= f.select(:book_id, books_select_options, {}, readonly: true)
```

The *generated html* code

```
<div>
   <input role="combobox" type="text" class="selectAutoCompleteInput" id="user_book_id-combobox">
   <select id="user_book_id" name="user[book_id]" readonly="readonly">
      <option value="5">ABC</option>
      <option value="6" selected="selected">DEF</option>
   </select>
   <div class="styledSelect">
      <span>DEF</span>
      <div class="styledSelect-caret-container"><i class="caret styledSelect-caret"></i></div>
   </div>
   <ul class="options">
      <li rel="5">ABC</li>
      <li rel="6">DEF</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Thank in advance

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have an autocomplete plugin set up somewhere. Try forcing a different class on the .select, or figure out what gem or plugin you are using and either remove it completely, or see how to bypass it for this particular select - most should have a way to turn it off.